# Execute PHP function on image onClick without loading the page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this HTML code. I want to click on the image and execute the PHP code without loading the PHP page. It will execute in background and update filed in the database.

How can I do this in a reliable way without loading the PHP page?

If I need to use **form**, how can I use it here? I have tried it but failed.

**html code**

```
<table>
<td align="center">
        <div class="round-button">
            <a href="viewStatus.php">
                <img name="myImg" src="images/City.png" alt="Home" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>
</table>
```

**php code**

```
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
    }

    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "myimageda");
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
    }
    mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `myDB` SET `state`=1 WHERE `id` = 1");

    ?>
```

Comment: You need to send an ajax request. You can not call PHP functions directly from client side

Comment: @MarcB Sorry, I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your answer in a simple and easiest way

**HTML**

```
<table>
<td align="center">
        <div class="round-button">
            <a href="#" onClick=rec('USE ANY VALUE HERE FOR IDENTITY')>
                <img src="images/City.png" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>
    ....
</table>
```

then use **javascript** to call that function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function rec(id) {
       $('#newCode').load('viewStatus.php?id=' + id);
    }        
</script>
```

and write your **PHP** code like below

```
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
    }

    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($connection, "myimageda");
    if (!$db_select) {
        die("Error: " . mysqli_error());
    }
    $ver = 'YOUR IDENTITY';
    if($ver == CONDITION) {
       mysqli_query($connection, "UPDATE `myDB` SET `state`=1 WHERE `id` = 1");
    }
    else {
    ...
    }
    ...
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, I use something like this:

```
<table>
<td align="center">
        <div class="round-button">
            <a href="viewStatus.php">
                <img name="myImg" src="images/City.png" alt="Home" onClick='Func'/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </td>
</table>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function Func() {

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "file.php",
            success:function(json){}, error:function(){}
        }) 
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `onClick='Func'` missing `()`

Answer (score 2):

You Cannot Call Php function on an Event. Use Ajax To Send Request To The Server 
http://www.ajax-tutor.com/post-data-server.html?userid=JOHNNY

Answer (score 1):

Php cannot be run on client machine hence you should use ajax for that purpose. send your data via ajax on a php page and execute your code on the basis of that data.

use something like this

```
 <img name="myImg" src="images/City.png" alt="Home" id="img" />

     $("#img").click(function(e){
       $.ajax({
              type:'post',
              data:q,
              url:'ajaxData.php',
              beforeSend: function(){
                    $("#msg").text("sending request to server...");
              },
              complete:function (){
                    $("#msg").text("request received and loaded");
              },
              success:function(result, textStatus, jqXHR) {     
                    $("#ajaxnotifier").html(result);
              },
              error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
              }
         })
     })
```

You can check the tutorial [ajax](http://a2znotes.blogspot.in/2014/08/load-data-via-ajax.html)